# A for loop with condition in it - Trying to make it a one liner

Tags: python

```
for row,col in targets:
    if (board[row][col] == -1 and ((col != 0 and board[row][col - 1] != -1) or (col != len(board) - 1 and board[row][col + 1] != -1) or (row != 0 and board[row - 1][col] != -1) or (row != len(board) - 1 and board[row + 1][col] != -1))): return 1000
return min(penalty)
```

Im trying to make it a one liner but doing:

```
return [min(penalty), 1000][True in[(board[row][col] == -1 and ((col != 0 and board[row][col - 1] != -1) or (col != len(board) - 1 and board[row][col + 1] != -1) or (row != 0 and board[row - 1][col] != -1) or (row != len(board) - 1 and board[row + 1][col] != -1)) for row,col in targets)]]
```

But its not the same thing.

Comment: Why is it that you would like to make it 1 line?

Comment: It is incredibly hard to read already

Comment: You should be turning that into *more* lines, not fewer.

Comment: I know its not very readable, but trust me I have a good reason for doing it on one line, and I'd be glad for some help because all my tries fail.

Comment: What's your "good reason"? I can't think of any

Comment: Ok, how about that: I need to fix one of my assignments, and the auto grader is based of how many lines you have changed during your fix, therefore I need a one liner for this function. As sad as it seems, it will help my grade if it works.

Comment: Then tell your course coordinators the auto grader is awful and should be improved

Comment: I will, thanks for any further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
return 1000 if any(condition(r, c) for r, c in targets) else min(penalty)
```

Here, `condition()` is your long inner condition.

But this will be harder to read and no faster than what you have already.